# Book with alien on spaceship who wears helmet to control slaves

Tags: story-identification, books, mind-control

I’m looking for a book I read as a child (early nineties) about an alien who used a spaceship and was part of a wider empire of aliens. They controlled millions with their mind.

In a part of the book, an alien was developing and wearing a helmet to extend their power, but tried using it at some crucial moment - and the helmet failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Niven, [Known Space](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/KnownSpace), stories involving the Slavers? One of the stories was adapted for animated Star Trek.

- Alien.
- Empire (dead by the time of the story, however).
- Psi-amplifier technology.

Comment: This might be an imperfectly remembered _[World of Ptavvs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ptavvs)_.

Comment: The word 'Thrint' revives a certain memory - I'm going to have a look at 'World of Ptavvs'!